# WCF Error Not Found with large objects

Tags: silverlight, wcf, client

I am having an issue with a WCF service call. The service takes a complex object that has many lists of objects inside of it. The problem occurs when the object gets too large. I am getting a communication exception that says Not Found. The call works as long as the item is not too large. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the relevant part of the client config file:

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICartService" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
            <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
    <endpoint address="../Services/CartService.svc"
              binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICartService"
              contract="AccessPoint.RichClient.Wcf.ICartService"
              name="BasicHttpBinding_ICartService" />
</client>
```

The web.config file has the following content:

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpLargeMessage" closeTimeout="00:02:00"
                 openTimeout="00:02:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:02:00"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="CartService.CartServiceBehavior"
             name="AccessPoint.WcfServices.CartService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="CartServiceBehavior"
                  binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpLargeMessage"
                  contract="AccessPoint.WcfServices.ICartService" />
</service>

<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CartService.CartServiceBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph ="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CartServiceBehavior">
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: Can you add the exact Exception and stacktrace? And how large is large? MB's? GB's? TB's?

Comment: Here is the stack trace from the outer exception:   at System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.ChannelBase`1.EndInvoke(String methodName, Object[] args, IAsyncResult result)
   at AccessPoint.WcfServices.CartWcfS.CartWcfSClient.CartWcfSClientChannel.EndSaveCart(IAsyncResult result)

Comment: and the stack trace for the inner exception:    at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)

Comment: I am not sure how large the message is. It's a complex object but I would guess that it is under 1MB.

Comment: I figured it out. I had two services that have similar names - one which is being deprecated. I was using the wrong config name. The new service had not been added to the web.config file yet.

Answer (score 0):

Any server error will be reflected in Silverlight as a "Not Found" exception. You need to either use some network sniffing tool (such as Fiddler) to see if the response has some additional information about the error, or [enable tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) at the server side to see why it's returning a non-successful response.

The post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlightws/archive/2010/09/23/debugging-wcf-services-in-silverlight.aspx has a video with lots of information about debugging WCF services in Silverlight.

Comment: Nothing shows up in Fiddler so I am guessing that the failure occurs before anything gets sent.

Comment: Try enabling tracing on the server then to see if there is some additional information there.